# React: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm sending a uid a token and two form inputs from formik to my django rest api for a password reset. When i do so i receive a 400 error with a response that i'm missing the new_password1 and new_password2:

```
{"new_password1":["This field is required."],"new_password2":["This field is required."]}
```

I assume this is caused by the fact that i wrapped the values inside the uid and token like this:

```
axios.post(API.auth.passwordResetConfirm, {uid, token, values} )
```

If i just do this then it will give me a response asking for the uid and the token but not the passwords:

```
axios.post(API.auth.passwordResetConfirm, values )
```

How can i send the two passwords and the uid aswell as the token without the values being "nested" like this (If that is the problem which i think it is)?
[image: Request Payload]

This is the entire code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router"
import axios from "axios"
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
import { API } from '../api'

export function ResetConfirm() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)
    const { uid } = useParams()
    const { token } = useParams()
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(token);

    function handleSubmit(values, { resetForm }) {
        setLoading(true)
        axios.post(API.auth.passwordResetConfirm, {uid, token, values} )
            .then(res => {
                resetForm()
                setSuccess(true)
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {success && "You will receive a verification email."}
            {loading && "Loading..."}
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    new_password1: '',
                    new_password2: '',
                }}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                {({ errors, touched }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <Field name="new_password1">
                            {({ field, form }) => (
                                <label className="mt-3 block">
                                    <span className="text-gray-700">New password</span>
                                    <input
                                    {...field}
                                    type="text"
                                    className="
                                        mt-1
                                        block
                                        w-full
                                        rounded-md
                                        border-gray-300
                                        shadow-sm
                                        focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50
                                    "
                                    placeholder=""
                                    style={
                                        form.touched.new_password1 && form.errors.new_password1 ? (
                                            { border: '2px solid var(--primary-red)'}
                                        ) : null
                                    }
                                    />
                                </label>
                            )}
                        </Field>
                        <Field name="new_password2">
                            {({ field, form }) => (
                                <label className="mt-3 block">
                                    <span className="text-gray-700">New password</span>
                                    <input
                                    {...field}
                                    type="text"
                                    className="
                                        mt-1
                                        block
                                        w-full
                                        rounded-md
                                        border-gray-300
                                        shadow-sm
                                        focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50
                                    "
                                    placeholder=""
                                    style={
                                        form.touched.new_password2 && form.errors.new_password2 ? (
                                            { border: '2px solid var(--primary-red)'}
                                        ) : null
                                    }
                                    />
                                </label>
                            )}
                        </Field>
                        <button className="mt-3 bg-blue-100 rounded-md shadow-sm text-lg px-5 py-3 hover:bg-blue-200" 
                            type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </Form>
                )}

            </Formik>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r This worked. Thank you so much. I will mark it as the correct answer if you want to put your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To un-nest `values` you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).

```js
console.log({ uid, token, ...values });
// {
//   uuid: "1",
//   token: "asdf",
//   new_password1: "Password123",
//   new_password2: "Password123",
// }
```

Note that if `values` includes the key `uid` or `token`, it will override the value of `uid`/`token`. So you have to make sure that in only includes whitelisted keys.

Alternatively you could reverse the order. `{ ...values, uid, token }`. This will set the key/values of `values` first, then set the values of `uid` and `token` (overriding the previous value if present).

```js
const uid = "1";
const token = "asdf";
const values = {
  new_password1: "Password123",
  new_password2: "Password123",
  uid: "2",
};

console.log({ uid, token, ...values });
console.log({ ...values, uid, token });
```